# How can I reference the ListView DataContext from within the ListView.ItemTemplate in XAML?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listview, data-binding

I have a ListView whose DataContext is set to my ViewModel. The ListView.ItemsSource is set to a Collection Property of the ViewModel. There is a Property called MyIndex say on this ViewModel. The value of MyIndex changes during the execution of my project.

I need a way to access in XAML 'MyIndex' from within the ItemTemplate of the ListView so that I can change aspects of each ListViewItem based on the value of MyIndex.

I can't use TemplatedParent and then the .Parent property of the ListViewItem in the binding as .Parent isn't the ListView.

Here is some pseudo XAML to illustrate better what I mean.

```html
            <ListView ItemsSource="ItemsCollection">
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <ItemContainerTemplate>
                        <Grid Background="{Binding <some xaml to reference MyIndex Property of ListView.DataContext to use in Converter>}">

                        </Grid>
                    </ItemContainerTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

I'm not experienced with WPF.

Comment: Why isn't `MyIndex` a property of the data item class?

Comment: @Clemens, MyIndex represents the index of a specific ListViewItem whose Background I want to change. So, as MyIndex changes the respective ListViewItem's background does and the previous ListViewItem returns to its old background. I thought the XAML would do this, but no. Instead it changes all the ListViewItems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. That way, you can use the DataContext of the parent in the children.

```
        <ListView ItemsSource="ItemsCollection">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <ItemContainerTemplate>
                <Grid Background="{Binding DataContext.MyIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListView}}">

                </Grid>
            </ItemContainerTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
```

Comment: Hi Lupu Silviu, thank you for your response. I'm having trouble confirming if this works. I've changed the binding to how you have said. I can see the code stepping into my ValueConverter that takes the MyIndex property. The converter is returns a Colors.Red say but the background of grid on which the binding is happening doesn't change.

Comment: @Cleve Because the type of the Background property is `Brush`, your converter should return a Brush, not a Color, e.g. `Brushes.Red`.

Comment: @Clemens, Thanks!

Comment: Still got an issue though as it's not doing what I want. As MyIndex changes value I only want THAT ListviewItem whose index in the ListView matches MyIndex to be affected. Is that possible? I appreciate this is a slightly different question. Sorry.